# Refreshing ionic page after navigate url to other page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Iam working on an ionic app edit profile and view profile. After editing the details of edit page it will navigate to View profile page.

I want the view profile page to be refresh after navigating.

Here is the code from editprofile.ts:

firstly i used like below for navigating

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/view-profile');
```

Through google search i added this to refresh the view profile after navigating

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/view-profile')
        .then(() => {
          window.location.reload();
        });
```

Now what happening is , firstly it is redirecting to view profile page and with out refreshing it is directly redirecting to Home page and home page is refreshing.

Please help me how can i refresh only View profile page after navigating from edit profile page.

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you are trying to refresh page in order to refresh data, maybe your data fetching is happening in `ngOnInit`?  If that's the case, you can try using `ionViewWillEnter` instead, as ionic caches components, so `ngOnInit` does not fire when going "back" to previously loaded components. [How Ionic Handles Life of a Page](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle#how-ionic-handles-the-life-of-a-page)

Answer (score 0):

You should (almost) never use location.reload() in ionic. That's for (browser) websites, in ionic you will get a blank screen for a moment, which is quite ugly.

There are several ways to accomplish what you want. In general you should always pass the same objects through different pages, and Angular takes care of updating the view when you change a property.

This means, if you have an object like this:

```
profile = {
    ID: 34,
    name: "Anthony",
    lastname: "Hopkins",
    age: "80"
}
```

You should pass this object to the EditProfile page, so when you change something in that screen, you will come back to the profile and the view will already be updated. That's the magic of Angular data-binding.

It may happen that, when you enter the EditProfile page, you make another API call to load more information. In that case, do not create a new **profile** object. Instead add properties to the previous profile object:

```
profile['city'] = 'London';
```

---

But ok, let's imagine this is impossible for you right now. In that case, when you return to the Profile page, make the API call again and replace your current profile object. Angular will refresh the view:

```
ngOnInit() {  // or constructor
    // do not get user data here, instead call a method
    this.getUserProfile();
}

// Call this method, instead of location.reload()
getUserProfile() {
    API.getProfile( profile => {
        this.profile = profile;  // view will refresh
    });
}
```

If the problem is that you don't know how to pass parameters from one page to another, then search how to solve that doubt, but do not try to avoid it.

You can pass parameters using a service, for example. Services are kept as a single instance through the whole app execution. So you can set service.param in one page, and get service.param in the other page.